# Electron: Can same channel name use for ipcMain.on and ipcMain.handle?

Tags: electron, ipc, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

Can we register the same channel for ipcMain.on method and ipcMain.handle()?

For eg:

```
ipcMain.handle('test', async(event,args) => {
    let result = await somePromise();
    return result;
});

ipcMain.on('test', async(event,args) => {
    event.returnValue = await somePromise();
});
```

Will the above code, give the error **No handler register for 'test'?** if ipcRenderer called this via invoke and sendSync in an order?

for eg:

```
ipcRenderer.invoke('test', data).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    return result;
});

someFunction(data) {
    return ipcRenderer.sendSync('test', data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those things that you can easily test out.

Looking at their [code](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/fb11a12d5b572201d6b1a24d6288fe2ccebb9ae6/lib/browser/ipc-main-impl.ts#L23) for `ipcMain.handle`, they store the channel name in an `_invokeHandlers` map that seems isolated from the rest of the module (meaning from `ipcMain.on`).

In fact, `ipcMain` extends an [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener), which is a Node class that maintains its own internal structure for managing events (This is the module where `on` and `once` are defined).

So you should be able to safely use both `ipcMain.on("test", ...)` and `ipcMain.handle("test", ...)` as long as you trigger them using the appropriate mechanism: `send`/`sendSync` corresponds with `on`/`once` and `invoke` corresponds with `handle`/`handleOnce`.